# как запустить сайт локально

Tags: php, html

Загрузил сайт с timeweb. В корне лежит index.php
Как продолжить работу с ним ,если нужно поправить верстку и стили?

Comment: Так, файлы которые ты загрузил себе на ПК? Чтобы запустить сайт локально, тебе нужен XAMPP.

Comment: ну и в вопросе не будет лишним указать OS

Comment: @JZ_52 а как дальше работать с кодом ?

Comment: Открываешь файлы в любом редакторе(хоть в блокноте), в youtube есть много роликов как работать с XAMPP и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта.

Можешь через FTP подключится к твоему серверу(хостингу) и редактировать файлы через filezilla. А если есть такая возможность, удобнее подключится через sFTP, то есть подключить твой сервер как сетевой диск. Для этого используется любой sftp менеджер. Тогда сможешь работать с файлами твоего сайта напрямую, все изменения будут доступны всем в реальном времени на твоем сайте. **Этот способ не очень хороший, так как можно сломать сайт.**

Более хороший вариант это установить какой-нибудь xampp, openserver (или хотябы устаревший denwer) и также работать с файлами сайта. Если после внесённых изменений всё работает как надо - можно через те же FTP/sFTP заливать изменения на сайт.